# gzip working on localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzip

I'm implementing gzip compression using an HttpModule; this is what it looks like:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest));
}

private void context_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();

    if (url.Contains("/ClientFiles"))
    {
        string AcceptEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) && AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this on my local machine, I see that the files are gzipped and everything works. When I run the same code on my shared hosting server, which doesn't do compression (ie. files aren't compressed by default), the files are also gzipped but the content is just a bunch of characters that don't decompress. Why is that and how do I fix it?

*I only want to implement gzip using an HttpModule so no IIS answer please.*

Comment: Have you check the headers? Does your server returns Content-Encoding?

Comment: Try capturing and comparing the responses for both cases using Fiddler. What do the response headers contain when you hit the hosting server? The hoster may be replacing or adding headers. Are there missing headers? Difference in response/content sizes?

Comment: In the web.config file, I register the HttpModule in <system.webServer> and in <system.web> May be it's compressing twice. Which section should I register the HttpModule?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your shared hosting server has already enabled gzip compression (so sorry, this is kind of an "IIS answer" ...) and that the content is thus compressed twice.

You could easily check this by temporarily disabling your own compression code and check if the content is compressed anyway.

Comment: I thought that too but it's not the case: the files are not compressed coming out of the server. Made an edit to clarify.

Comment: In the web.config file, I register the HttpModule in <system.webServer> and in <system.web> May be it's compressing twice. Which section should I register the HttpModule?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact issue for you ever figure out what it was?